# Convert daily stock returns to weekly stock returns

Tags: pandas, finance

I'm very new to pandas and I'm trying to convert daily stock return into **weekly** stock returns by finding the product of (1 + return) for each day Monday to Friday.

Here is an example of what i have so far (data is just an example, not real numbers):

```
 In[1]: df
 In [2]:
      Date       AAPL      NFLX       INTC  
 2019-09-09      0.01    0.0012    0.00873
 2019-09-10     0.014    0.0074  0.0837738
 2019-09-11    0.0123  0.007123    0.09383
 2019-09-12    0.0028   0.07234     0.0484
 2019-09-13   0.00172    0.8427    0.09484
```

My dataset is much larger than what I'm showing. But essentially I just want to find the product of (1+return) for every consecutive Monday to Friday.

The ideal output would be a dataframe with fridays as indices, and then weekly return values displayed under the stock tickers

Comment: what does (1+return) mean? also if there are missing dates, what will you do with the data discard it? can you show your intended output [ask]

Comment: By 1+return I think he means compound interest because he wants to know how that stock performed in a specific week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line of code below should do it:

```
(1+df).resample('W-FRI').prod()-1
```

What the line above is doing is resampling the (1 + daily return) (check pandas resample documentation for further information) to a weekly frequency with Friday set as the resampling day ('W-FRI'). Finally, the prod() is multiplying the (1 + daily return) when weekly resampling is perfomed to return the accumulated return for each week.